# The Guinand-Weil explicit formula for Hecke characters

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions, zeta-functions

The Guinand-Weil formula for the Riemann zeta function is
\begin{aligned}&\Phi (1)+\Phi (0)-\sum _{\rho }\Phi (\rho )\\={}&\sum _{p,m}{\frac {\log(p)}{p^{m/2}}}{\Big (}F(\log(p^{m}))+F(-\log(p^{m})){\Big )}-{\frac {1}{2\pi }}\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\varphi (t)\Psi (t)\,dt\end{aligned}

where $\rho$ runs over the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function, $p$ runs over the primes, $m$ runs over the positive integers, $F$ is a rapidly decreasing function, and $\Phi(1/2+it)=\varphi(t)$ is the Fourier transform of $F$.

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_for_L-functions#Weil%27s_explicit_formula):

> More generally, the Riemann zeta function and the L-series can be replaced by the Dedekind zeta function of an algebraic number field or a Hecke L-series. The sum over primes then gets replaced by a sum over prime ideals.

**Q**: What is the Guinand-Weil formula for Hecke L-functions, where there is a sum over Hecke L-function zeros of the Fourier transform of a rapidly decreasing function on the LHS, and a summation over prime ideals on the RHS?

Comment: See [there](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X06002757)   the difference is that the conjugate L-function comes into play, obtaining  $\Phi (1)+\Phi (0)-\sum _{\beta }\Phi (\beta )$ $=\sum _{P,m} \frac{\log(N(P))}{N(P)^{m/2}}(\psi(P^m) F(\log(N(P)^{m}))+\overline{\psi}(P^m) F(-\log(N(P)^{m})+ trivial\ terms$

Comment: @reuns Thanks for your answer!